# Nodejs return not whole response

Tags: node.js

This code return whole page, and all ok, but I need to return it to another function.

```
var host = 'http://example.com';
    var getPage = function( URL, callback ) {
        var request = http.request( { "host": host, "path": URL, "port": 80 }, function( response ) {
            var str = '';
            response.on('data', function( chunk ) {
                str += chunk;
            });
            response.on('end', function() {
                console.log(str);
            });
        }).on('error', function(err) {
            console.log( err );
            callback( err, 303 );
        }).end();
    };

    getPage('/page/', function( text, status ) {
    //do something
    });
```

This code return maybe 50% of page.

```
var host = 'http://example.com';
    var getPage = function( URL, callback ) {
        var request = http.request( { "host": host, "path": URL, "port": 80 }, function( response ) {
            var str = '';
            response.on('data', function( chunk ) {
                str += chunk;
            });
            response.on('end', function() {
                callback( str, response.statusCode );
            });
        }).on('error', function(err) {
            console.log( err );
            callback( err, 303 );
        }).end();
    };

    getPage('/page/', function( text, status ) {
      parsePage( text, URL );
    });
```

As far as I understand, nodejs does not manage to convey whole variable in the function due to asynchrony, as his "slow down"?

Comment: From what I understand, `http://example.com` is a host.

Comment: I think, if you call your `getPage` function as `getPage('http://example.com', '/', function( text, status ) {` it will work just fine

Comment: Also, you'll have to update your `getPage` function definition as `var getPage = function(host, URL, callback ) {`

Comment: The problem is that everything is working just on some pages of the variable is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is in link:

If I go to link: "/razgruzochnye-sistem**і**" I've got an error, becouse last character in link is not an english char.

Solution:

```
URL = URL.split("/").map(function(val) { return encodeURI(val); }).join('/');
```